# could not find MavenWrapperMain class, but is contained within .m2 in the directory

Tags: java, maven

So here's a new one, for me… I'm working with one of the Spring Boot guides, and getting the

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain
```

error when running

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

(or any Maven Wrapper command)

That said, I see the `wrapper` jar within `.mvn` where I would expect it to be.

Has anyone else hit this? It seems like it must be a system-level issue because I've had no issue with this in the past.

Here is the repo I am running this command on: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-scheduling-tasks.git

Comment: **Launched from the root folder**: I have this error: `[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local ([home]\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]`

Comment: **Launched from the `initital` folder**: I have this error: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.10.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project gs-scheduling-tasks: Unable to find a suitable main class, please add a 'mainClass' property`

Comment: **Launched from the `complete` folder**: Spring Boot application starts, prints the current time every 5 seconds.

Comment: Before all just after cloning the git repository I launched from the root folder: `mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper`

Comment: @HonzaZidek can you clarify what you mean by "launched"? I understand what you're getting at, the `complete` folder is giving me the same issues though.

Comment: "launched" = "ran the command" :) See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/launch: "*to load into a computer's memory and run; launch a program*". Launching the `mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper` command is the first thing you have to do before you do anything else. If it is the `complete` folder which gives you the error, I cannot help you as it *does* work for me and I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: @HonzaZidek Cool, thanks for confirming that. I'm going to spin up a clean OSX and see if I can isolate which versions of Maven and Java are causing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured this out, so posting for posterity:

If the Maven download was corrupted for whatever reason and didn't successfully download (due to loss of connectivity or other reasons), this error will throw.

Mitigation is (within Spring Boot application folder):

```
rm -rf .mvn
./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

Answer (score 4):

Initial project is an empty project so when you run `./mvnw spring-boot:run` in this folder the message is clear and tells you that there is no main class in the project to run as a Spring Boot application.

If you run the command in the complete folder you run the project which has all the logic of the tutorial.

If you cd in the root folder and you run mvnw from inside complete or initial folders you get that message because it is like you cd to a completely irrelevant folder like /test/project (you can try that).

What mvnw does is tries to find and run a .pom file where in all folders except for complete and initial is not present.

Comment: I agree that is what I'd expect, the problem is that I am getting this error while inside `/Code/Java:Spring/gs-rest-service/complete` … which seems to be the correct location.

Answer (score 1):

try to delete it from .m2 directory and rebuild again, i once had a similar problem and solved only when i deleted the jar from .m2 and rebuild it again

Answer (score 0):

You have to add configuration

```
<configuration>
        <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
        <layout>ZIP</layout>
 </configuration>
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html

It presents in complete directory but no any class or annotated class (as an option instead of configuration section)

Just finished in 'complete' on Windows

```
[INFO] Installing D:\projects\edu_test\gs-scheduling-tasks\complete\pom.xml to C:\Users\alex\.m2\repository\org\springframework\gs-scheduling-tasks\0.1.0\gs-scheduling-tasks-0.1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```